# Input.GetKeyUp works wrong after Inputfield user input in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, key, input-field

The problem is just like what I explained in Title.
After InputField user input, all the other **character(such as KeyCode.A, KeyCode.B, ... KeyCode.Z)** input seems not working for **GetKeyDown(), GetKeyUp(), GetKey()**, while special keys works such as KeyCode.LeftArrow, KeyCode.Delete, etc.

```
void Update(){
    // search shortcut with Enter key     
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        if (searchField.text.Trim() != "")
        {
            // do something
        }
        searchField.DeactivateInputField();
    }
}
```

After some search, I found DeactivateInputField() function and I executed in the end of if statement to prevent it. But it seems helpful but sometimes not. I mean, after insert **searchField.DeactivateInputField();** sometimes this problem doesn't occur, sometimes it occurs. I am lost..

I am guessing InputField event system is eating keys but only character keys..
I can't use **Input.eatKeyPressOnTextFieldFocus** because I'm using Unity5 and it is deprecated.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how make to make ios keyboard's return key submit input in unity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803135/how-make-to-make-ios-keyboards-return-key-submit-input-in-unity)

Comment: It's not really that easy to do this. Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670276/how-to-detect-done-button-in-softkeyboard-unity3d  But note that you really **don't use** Input.GetKeyDown with UI ! ... just keep reading the .text of the InputField

Comment: Like this .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29112180/294884 and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28293066/294884

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I don't think it's related to my problem. How is it related? I am not asking how to make return key has submit effect. I already implement it. I'm asking something like bug which character buttons are not working after return key.